# How to adjust notification font size at ubuntu mate 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mate, notification, ubuntu-mate

Is there a way to adjust notifications font size at ubuntu mate 20.04? 
There is no such option at the [pop up notifications in control center](https://imgur.com/mTZVHfC).

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-themes) is the official Mate-themes repository. I couldn't find anything regarding the notification font-size or OSD font-size except some settings like [this](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-themes/blob/master/desktop-themes/Blue-Submarine/cinnamon/cinnamon.css#L1798) which is only applicable for cinnamon . I don't know whether it's applicable in mate or not. But unfortunately there's a little or even no documentation concerning gnome themes.

Comment: Some DEs like Cinnamon or KDE are more customizable in that sense.For example in KDE plasma you can easily change the global font and it also affects the notification font-size.